# Collect specific filenames using regex

Tags: python, python-3.x, regex

I have a list of filenames. I want to collect filenames that are exactly one of these three patterns:

```
foo.ext
foo-*.ext
foo.*.ext
```

`foo` is a variable, `*` can be anything, `ext` is a file extension.

How would I do that using regex?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
import pathlib

me = 'saeed'

sorted(pathlib.Path('.').glob(f'{me}.ext'))
sorted(pathlib.Path('.').glob(f'{me}-*.ext'))
sorted(pathlib.Path('.').glob(f'{me}.*.ext'))
```

Result:

```
>>> sorted(pathlib.Path('.').glob(f'{me}.ext'))
[PosixPath('saeed.ext')]
>>> sorted(pathlib.Path('.').glob(f'{me}-*.ext'))
[PosixPath('saeed-hi.ext'), PosixPath('saeed-oops.ext')]
>>> sorted(pathlib.Path('.').glob(f'{me}.*.ext'))
[PosixPath('saeed.you.ext')]
```

You can use `f-string` and `pathlib`.

These are the files in my current path:

```
>>> os.system('ls')
saeed-hi.ext  saeed-oops.ext  saeed.ext  saeed.you.ext  saeedyou.ext
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a regex:

```
import re

def filter_files(filenames, foo, ext):
    pat = fr'{foo}([-.].*)?\.{ext}'
    return [filename for filename in filenames
            if re.match(pat.format(foo=foo, ext=ext), filename)]

filenames = ['hello.txt', 'hello-1.txt', 'hello.2.txt', 'hello3.txt', 'hello-4.doc']
```

Usage:

```
>>> filter_files(filenames, 'hello', 'txt')
['hello.txt', 'hello-1.txt', 'hello.2.txt']
```